# Is there a hebrew term for Jahrzeit?

Tags: words, yahrtzeit

The term "Yahrtzeit" presumably comes from the German word Jahrzeit. ("Jahr" meaning "year" and "zeit" meaning "time".) Is there a hebrew word or phrase (or spelling) for the concept of a yahrtzeit?

(If there is one, it should be added to the yahrtzeit tag.)

Comment: I can't remember the exact word right now, but the shoresh is "Zecher", and no, not Yizkor.

Comment: I think you're incorrect that English _yahrzeit_ is from German. I think it's from Yiddish. [The OED (online edition)](http://oed.com/view/Entry/231129#eid) agrees with me: "Etymology: Yiddish, < Middle High German _jarzît_ anniversary, < Old High German _jâr_ year (noun 1) + _zît_ time."

Comment: @msh210 - Where do you think Yiddish got it from?

Comment: The OED says where Yiddish got it from: Middle High German. That's German's ancestor as well as Yiddish's, but isn't the same as what we now call "German".

Comment: @msh210 I'm very much aware of what German is. I don't care about the OED. The word Jahr and Zeit haven't changed between those two evolutions of Hochdeutsch. Word usage and grammar have changed, but those words still exist. As far as this conversation goes, German refers to the several evolutions of Germanic languages represented by modern German. Don't get me started on Yiddish. Excuse me for saying this, but Yiddish is a "crowd sourced" language.  If it's from Yiddish, it's really from German or wherever. What I like to call Hickdeutsch.

Comment: The Ben Ish Hai says that the word Yahrtzeit means Hilula in 'Ashkenazit - Yidish.' Just an interesting thought,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think in modern Hebrew it's [אזכרה](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%94) - Azkara.

Comment: this is what the Israeli's I know call it.

Comment: Thats the word I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

The Sefardim typically refer to this as הילולה.  (Hee-loo-lah).

http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94

Comment: Is it not spelled with an _alef_ at the end, being an Aramaic noun?

Comment: no (at least not in modern Hebrew).  I will add a link to the Hebrew Wikipedia article on the word.

Answer (score 3):

I always thought of it as יום הזכרון

[Kitzur Shulchan Oruch 128(6)](http://www.kitzur.net/main.php?siman=128&black=false&nk=1) translates someone who has a יאר צייט  as a בעל יום זכרון So יום זכרון (without the ה) could have been a translation if not for אזכרה.

Comment: -1 יום הזכרון (without any qualifiers) refers to Israel's Memorial Day.